# Extending vue-bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I just started playing around with bootstrap-vue, and my question is, what is the best practice of extending components of a library like that. I just want some componenets to accept extra props. I opened the node_modules folder and tried messing with the files directly but they don't seem to change anything. Also I think the consensus is that doing it this way is a bad idea. So what is the best practice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html#ad). You can call the `extend` method of any component (because components are extensions of Vue) to add in your mixins.